# Tensorflow creating new variables even when graph is resued

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using TFLearn and Tensorflow to run a CNN. My current approach is rebuilding the model with each run because my batch size changes between training and testing. I noticed some memory issues and then when I investigated further I found that on each run I was recreating my entire model on the Graph even though I'm doing everything I think I can to reuse the graph. I'm not using the default graph, I'm holding the same instance of my graph throughout all training, and all of my variables have reuse set to true. As you can see in my Tensorboard output I have two sets of everything after my second training epoch and with each additional one I get another set. What can I do to make sure I only reuse the first set?

```
def build_and_run_model(self, num_labels, data, labels, holdout, holdout_labels, batch_size, checkpoint_directory=None, checkpoint_file=None, restore=False,
                        num_epochs=10, train=True, image_names=None, gpu_memory_fraction=0):
    if not self.graph:
        self.graph = tf.Graph()

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False), graph=self.graph) as session:
        tflearn.config.is_training(train, session)

        if train:
            keep_prob = .8
        else:
            keep_prob = 1

        # Building 'AlexNet'
        network = input_data(shape=[None, 227, 227, 3])
        network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
        network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
        network = local_response_normalization(network)
        network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
        network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
        network = local_response_normalization(network)
        network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
        network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
        network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
        network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
        network = local_response_normalization(network)
        network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
        network = dropout(network, keep_prob)
        network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
        network = dropout(network, keep_prob)
        network = fully_connected(network, num_labels, activation='softmax')
        network = regression(network, optimizer="adam",
                             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                             learning_rate=self.build_learning_rate(), batch_size=batch_size)

        if not self.model:
            model = self.model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_dir="./tflearn_logs/", checkpoint_path=checkpoint_directory + checkpoint_file, tensorboard_verbose=3)

        else:
            model = self.model

        if restore | (not train):
            logger.info("Restoring checkpoint from ' % s'." % (checkpoint_directory + checkpoint_file))
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_directory)
            logger.info("Loading variables from ' % s'." % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            model.load(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

        if train:
            model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=int(num_epochs), shuffle=True,
                      show_metric=True, batch_size=batch_size, snapshot_step=None,
                      snapshot_epoch=True, run_id='alexnet_imagerecog')
```

[image: Tensorboard with duplicated model]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a misunderstanding of what is meant by the default graph. I thought if I created the graph like I did above it would be used every time I ran that model, but that didn't appear to be the case. I've changed my code to build the model inside a block like so:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default() as g:
```

And I am no longer seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it as follows:
`with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:`